# InsertBefore() is not working with javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

`data` is responseXML from ajax request which returns `<b>Test Text</b>`
`data` is XMLDocument object
`streamObj` is DOM node of html page.

```
streamObj.insertBefore(data,streamObj.firstChild);
```

It is not inserting the xml fragment. why?

Comment: is It showing any error? Does the target node exist before this operation.

Comment: It is not showing any error in console

Comment: @Manish yes i had dumped data before using it and it shows XMLDocument object

Comment: Looks like we don't have enough information to work with. Your best bit is to create a [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem, post it to the question, and (if you like) also post it to http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com. That said, I'm not at all sure it's valid to put an XML DOM node into an HTML DOM document directly like that... (But again, you should be getting an error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

`data` which is being returned from an AJAX reponseXML , is whole `XMLDocument`. To get its root node it needed to be use `data.documentElement`
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_document_documentelement.asp

Comment: Rather than [w3fools](http://w3fools.com), I recommend going to [the source](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-87CD092) or a [*decent* meta-reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.documentElement).

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to believe there was no error for this in the error console. What browser are you using?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Mozilla firefox

Comment: @ fallenAngel: And sure enough, and if you go to Tools | Web Developer | Web Console to show the console, you'll see `HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy` Example: http://jsbin.com/ibamew/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/ibamew/1/edit). (This is also basically what you see in Chrome's console.)